# Need to manipulate string data using bash

Tags: bash, shell, name-value

I have data being displayed on the console in the following format:

```
 "name1",
 "value1",
 "name2",
 "value2",
 "name3",
 "value3",
 ...
 ...
```

I need to somehow manipulate this output so that it will be displayed in the following format:

```
 name1 : value1
 name2 : value2
 name3 : value3
 ...
 ...
```

I'm not very good with shell scripting but I know my options are sed, tr, or awk (or a combination of the aforementioned). I just can't figure out how to accomplish what it is I need here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe it into:

```
 | sed 's/^ *"\|", *$//g' | paste -d: - -
```

sed to remove the quotes, paste to join 2 consecutive lines together with a colon.

Comment: Perfect! I was struggling with the 'paste' portion of this problem -- never had to use it before so I wasn't aware that command existed. Thanks @glenn

Answer (score 1):

glenn jackmans' `paste` solution is quite elegant but I figured I'd throw in some other solutions.

With `sed` : `sed -ne '1~2{s/$/ : /;N;s/[",]\|\n //g;p}'`

For every odd line add `:` to the end, read the next line into the current pattern space (`N`), remove any quotes and commas and newline+space combinations and print.

With `awk` : `awk '{gsub(/[",]|^ */,"")} NR%2{printf $0 " : "} !(NR%2)'`

Replace all quotes, commas and line-leading sapces. For all odd lines (lines where `NR%2` is non-zero) append `:` and print without a newline. For all even lines (lines where `NR%2` is zero) print the line (finishing the previous line).